# Multiple choice ListView - getting all the checked items

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have just began using Adapters and I tried to make a simple application which displays a checkable list of strings and a button. Once the button is clicked, it displays all the checked items underneath in a TextView widget.

```
public class Checklist extends ListActivity {

private String[] items={"Hi","My","Name","is","Adrian"};
ListView lv; 
Button btn;
TextView tv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);



    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            long[] ids = lv.getCheckedItemIds();
            String s = "";

            for (int i=0; i<ids.length;i++) {
                s=s+ids[i]+"\n";
            }
            tv.setText(s);
    }
    });
}
```

}

I have come up with this code but does not want to work because this array

```
long[] ids = lv.getCheckedItemIds();
```

does not actually get any values. So I looked into API and it says that the adapter

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);
```

must have stable IDs. Then I checked that as well and the adapter does not have stable IDs

```
hasStableIDs() == false
```

How Can I go about that problem?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do, do you want to show ids or the content of those selected items?

Comment: For now I just want to show the content of the long[] ids array

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is, instead of using an array like you are doing with`long[] ids` you'll have to create a SparseBooleanArray objetc, like this `SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = your_list.getCheckedItemPositions();`